# KeyListener doesn't detect key presses

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

In my JFrame I have this listener:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

This has been working fine until about 10 minutes ago. Now when I press a key, keyPressed() never even gets called. I tested this with eclipse debugger.

I have no idea what happened. Any ideas?

EDIT #1: This is also happening with a button that I have set up. the action listener does not recognize when the button is clicked.

EDIT #2: Ok So I was able to narrow it down. I have a JFrame, this frame has a main panel and also 2 action listeners (keyListener, the problematic one, and a mouse click listener, working fine). The main panel has two subpanels a and b. panel a has 2 buttons, one is not set up yet. It seems that these buttons are somehow conflicting with the keylistener making it so the key listener and buttons do not work. either way the mouse click listener still works.

Edit #3: Ok here is some simplified code:

The button is working, but the keyListener is not. I am hearing about focus a lot, if this is the problem how can I fix it?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class ListenerTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel mainPanel;
private JPanel panelA;
private JPanel panelB;
private JButton buttonA;
private JButton buttonB;

public ListenerTest() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    panelA = new JPanel();
    panelB = new JPanel();
    buttonA = new JButton("Button A");
    buttonB = new JButton("Button B");

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0.getKeyChar());
        }
    });


    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
        }
    });

    buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button A pressed!");                
        }
    });

    panelA.add(buttonA);
    panelA.add(buttonB);
    mainPanel.add(panelA);
    mainPanel.add(panelB);
    this.add(mainPanel);

    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ListenerTest();
}
}
```

Comment: What did you change in those critical 10 minutes and where?

Comment: I tried to undo as many changes as possible but nothing worked. I simply don't understand why the method never even gets called.

Comment: Try the usual: clean build, recompile, restart your IDE, restart your pc. It shouldn't make any difference but in my experiencing it does...

Comment: Try creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In creating a working minimal example, you might just run into the piece of code that causes the problem and understand it yourself. And if not, you'll have code to show us which we can run ourselves and give you better help.

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: Probably a question of **focus**.

Comment: *"(focus) if this is the problem how can I fix it?"*  That is indeed one of the problems that **key bindings** fixes!

Comment: @AndrewThompson are key bindings compatible with JFrame? I am getting an error for getInputMap() and getActionMap()

Comment: [`getInputMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap--) & [`getActionMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap--) are both methods of `JComponent` so simply add a `JComponent` (or `JPanel` etc.) to the frame and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an action for a specific key (for example: F2) to `panelA`, this seems to work:

```
public ListenerTest() {
    // Create components...

    panelA.getActionMap().put("saveAction", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("F2");
        }
    });

    //panelA.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "saveAction");
    panelA.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
              .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "saveAction");

    //this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    //mainPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    panelA.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    //buttonA.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Panel A: " + arg0.getKeyChar());
        }
    });

    // Rest of the code...
}
```

Adding the action also seems to have a side effect: the `KeyListener` seems to work again for `panelA`. The focus no longer goes to one of the buttons by default.

Note: when using `panelA.getInputMap()`, the key action only works when the buttons do not have the focus. Use `panelA.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` to make sure the action works when one of the buttons has the focus.

Comment: Nothing happens when you press F2?

Comment: I changed it to s but ya nothing happens

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like it when s is a string. I changed it to a char and it works. Thanks!